# Getting error "Unsupported RAM template"?

Tags: verilog

Getting error in "    reg [7:0] ram[63:0]; "
   Line.

I tried it the same code and it worked for single port ram but not 
   working for two port ram.

```
module two_port_ram(
input [7:0] data_a,
input [7:0] data_b,
input [5:0] add_a,
input [5:0] add_b,
input we_a,
input we_b,
input clk,
output reg [7:0] q_a,
output reg [7:0] q_b 
);

reg [7:0] ram[63:0];

always@ (posedge clk)
begin
if(we_a)
ram[add_a] <= data_a;
else
q_a <= ram[data_a];
end

always@ (posedge clk)
begin
if(we_b)
ram[add_b] <= data_b;
else
q_b <= ram[data_b];
end
endmodule
```

Unsupported RAM template

Comment: " reg [7:0] ram[63:0]; " facing problem in this line.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out the issue i mistakenly wrote q_a <= ram[data_a]; where it should have been q_a <= ram[add_a];
this resolved the issue.